# Linq to entities : left join without projection

Tags: linq-to-entities, left-join

I need some help on one thing.
I currently have 3 tables :
    House (id, name, isDisplayed)
    Rooms (id, name, isDisplayed)
    Pictures (id, name)

House can have O..* Rooms and Rooms can have 0..* Pictures

So simple case, i want all Houses with Rooms and Pictures

```
var query=db.Houses.Include(h=>h.Rooms).Include(h=>h.Rooms.Select(r=>r.Pictures));
```

This is working fine so ok :)

Now, let's say I want all the House and theirs Rooms (including pictures of the rooms) that have isDisplayed set to true and also House without Rooms

Using SQL, that would pretty easy but I'm using Linq to entities and I clearly don't want projections.

Do you see any way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: "clearly don't want projections"?  Not sure why you would say that.  Projections are a key part.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: You need to project to a new class/anonymous type.

An *Entity* is a representation of the data in your database and this allows the Entity Framework to track the changes to your Entity and push these modifications back to the database when you save. So all Entities that are being returned need to be unmodified. Otherwise, when you go to save, the Entity Framework would make all the database modifications you specified in your `select`, in your case it would remove all the records in your database with `isDisplayed = false`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you please give me an exemple of what you think ?

Comment: @user3206382 What example would you like me to provide? Projecting to new a class?

Answer (score 0):

db.Houses.Include(x=>x.Rooms.Select(e=>e.Pictures))
    .Where(x=>!x.Rooms.Any() || x.Rooms.Any(e=>e.Pictures.Any(v=>v.IsDisplayed))
    .ToList()